# Extension Methods not working properly C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, pass-by-value

So I have a simple method called `Invert`:

```
public static void Invert(this bool value)
{
    value = !value;
}
```

It is inside of a static class in a `.dll` file. Now when I go to a new Winforms project, I add the `.dll` as a reference and everything is good so far. Now when I do this:

```
bool test = true;
test.Invert();
```

I get no errors, but when I do:

```
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
```

It outputs `true`, as if nothing has changed. I am not sure if it because of what I am doing in the method or something else. But if I go:

```
MessageBox.Show((!test).ToString());
```

It outputs `false`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's working correctly. Because `bool` is a value type, it's passed as a value and the original variable (`test`) is not ever being changed.

Instead you should do something like:

```
public static bool Invert(this bool value) 
{ 
    return !value; 
}
```

However, creating a method that does what the language does itself is a bit of a waste of time.

I don't think extension methods will let you take a `this` parameter by reference, so you would have to use a regular static method, and call it the long way:

```
public static bool Invert(ref bool value) { value = !value; }

BooleanHelpers.Invert(ref test);
```

In the end, it's going to be a lot cleaner and easier (not to mention more obvious to other developers) to just do it this way:

```
test = !test;
```

Comment: I know it is a waste of time but I am just learning about extension methods and decided to try a simple one.

Answer (score 2):

Your extension method takes in the `bool` by value, not by reference. The body of the method is changing the local copy of the `bool`, not the original value owned by the caller.

Comment: So how could I make the method take it by reference?

Comment: @MatthewRz You can annotate the parameter with `ref`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is a value type, and you aren't passing it by reference. You need to assign the result of `Invert` to another or the same variable for it to persist.